# Active Directory authentication with winbind on ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: 14.04, pam, active-directory

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and all required packages are already installed and I have configured `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and `/etc/krb5.conf` file. The server is joined successfully to AD Server.

I am getting the below error while trying to login:

```
Apr 10 01:16:50 myserver sshd[9700]: input_userauth_request: invalid user dir+souvik.dhar [preauth]
Apr 10 01:17:01 myserver CRON[9703]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 10 01:17:01 myserver CRON[9703]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 10 01:17:01 myserver sshd[9700]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): getting password (0x00000008)
Apr 10 01:17:01 myserver sshd[9700]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD, Error message was: Wrong Password
Apr 10 01:17:01 myserver sshd[9700]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): user 'dir+souvik.dhar' denied access (incorrect password or invalid membership)
```

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you change the password to QWERTY+numbers only and try again?  If that does not help, can you use the fully qualified user name and try again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the date in your Linux system, try sync the time with the domain controller.

```
ntpdate dc.mydomain.local
```

Comment: The error says something about an incorrect password. What makes you think it's the date?

Comment: if the time is not synced with the DC the password does not match